# Hover Function not working in selenium webdriver for IE 11 browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, xpath, ie11

In `IE 11`, mouse hover is not working.It is `kendo-control`.Tried with each possible way.But anything is not working.The element is getting highlighted but it is not opening the list.

I want to hover first `Store Admin` link. After hovering when list appears need to click on `set store parameter`

[image]